# Develop a poller similar to MRTG

Tags: snmp, cisco-ios

Im developing a poller similar to MRTG/cacti in java and have a few queries.

How do I know if the device uses 64 bit counter or 32 bit counter. Also do I get the values from these counters or is there some other way of getting the bandwidth and packet transfers. These counters wrap after reaching their limit so I need to check to that as well ?
Also is there an OID to check the counter used....or can I assume that speeds greater than 10Mbs use 64 bit counters ??

Is 5 minutes a decent polling interval for the devices ??

Will the same OID work in all CISCO devices ?? Or do I need to check the IOS and change the OIDs accordingly ??

Comment: You should obtains the oid's from the `.mib` files per device.

Answer (score 1):

That's a lot of questions.

> How do I know if the device uses 64 bit counter or 32 bit counter.

If device is capable of using 64-bit devices you could poll them. You can check this with simple snmpwalk.

> Also do I get the values from these counters or is there some other
>   way of getting the bandwidth and packet transfers.

You should be able to count Mbps from counters.

> These counters wrap after reaching their limit so I need to check to
>   that as well ?

Yes, the counters start over after reaching 32-bit/64-bit max value.

> Also is there an OID to check the counter used....or can I assume that
>   speeds greater than 10Mbs use 64 bit counters ??

No, haven't heard about that. And you can assume that with speeds greater than 300Mbps you should use 64-bit counters.

> Is 5 minutes a decent polling interval for the devices ??

30 seconds more likely.

> Will the same OID work in all CISCO devices ?? Or do I need to check
>   the IOS and change the OIDs accordingly ??

You should check the model of the device, not IOS.